# Error when implementing autocomplete with Cakephp 3

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I'm trying to adapt [this tutorial](https://dcblog.dev/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui) for my project in cakephp 3.8. I have a user table and I want to do a search by name.

After generating the code with the bake and inserting the search field, my index.ctp looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?= $this->Form->create('', ['type' => 'get']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->control('keyword', array('class' => 'auto','value' => '','label' => false,'required' => true));?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Search')); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end();  ?>

    <nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
        <ul class="side-nav">
            <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
            <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New User'), ['action' => 'add']) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="large-9 medium-8 columns content">
        <h3><?= __('Users') ?></h3>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('created') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
                    <td><?= h($user->nome) ?></td>
                    <td><?= h($user->created) ?></td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
                        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="paginator">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first')) ?>
                <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
                <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
                <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
                <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>') ?>
            </ul>
            <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter(['format' => __('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total')]) ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "/users",
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in this part, I don't know how to adapt.

```
 //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "users",
        minLength: 1
    });
```

Here in this part, I don't know how I could adapt.

My UsersController.php looked like this:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $users= $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => [
                'name like' => '%'. $this->request->getQuery('keyword') . '%',            
            ]
        ];
        
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
```

At the moment, for any search I get "No search results.", Even if the name exists in the database.
I appreciate if anyone can analyze. Any comment is welcome!

Comment: try `'name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%',` and  change `source: "search.php"`, to `source: "/users",`

Comment: I made the code change and it remains the same. I even removed the jquery to try to do the search, but it doesn't return the result!

Comment: what happen when you try source like /users.json ? (try in browser) and LIKE not like

Comment: I removed the 'name' => 'search' from the search field and the search worked. But the autocomplete still doesn't work. When do I enter the user.json browser? gives the error:Error: Users.jsonController could not be found.